# Last value of the loop is beign added through-out map?

Tags: java

Guys I have a simple Problem which i am not able to figure out! Please help

```
     for(Investor investor : registerdUsers) {
            formatedDate = sdf.format(investor.getRegistrationDate());
            if(dateWiseInvestorsMap.containsKey(formatedDate)) {
                dateWiseInvestorsList.add(investor);
                dateWiseInvestorsMap.put(formatedDate, dateWiseInvestorsList);
            } else {
                dateWiseInvestorsList.clear();
                dateWiseInvestorsList.add(investor);
                dateWiseInvestorsMap.put(formatedDate, dateWiseInvestorsList);
                System.out.println("here goes date"+formatedDate);
            }
        }
```

EDIT : added print statement

```
for(Map.Entry<String, List<Investor>> entry :dateWiseInvestorsMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("date :" + entry.getKey() + ", count :" + entry.getValue().size());
        }
```

Here is the code , Last value is added in all values of map.

Expected :

```
date :2012-01-01 Count:7
date :2012-01-02 Count:13
date :2012-01-03 Count:12
date :2012-01-04 Count:10
date :2012-01-05 Count:11
date :2012-01-06 Count:8
```

Current :

```
date :2012-01-01 Count:8
date :2012-01-02 Count:8
date :2012-01-03 Count:8
date :2012-01-04 Count:8
date :2012-01-05 Count:8
date :2012-01-06 Count:8
```

Comment: I'm not sure how's the code you posted is related. Unclear for me.

Comment: The Expected and Current are just print statements i have written!! which i get when i iterate map!

Comment: Current out put never resulting by this code. Post the relevant code here.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera Please Find the Edit!

Comment: Can you print out the map at each loop?  I have a feeling that your key may be colliding.  Perhaps a custom hashcode method?

Comment: @CodeChimp Why cant i print the map on each loop ?

Comment: You can.  I am asking you to do it.  Print the key/value pairs at each iteration and see if the values there are matching what you expect.  This will show when your `Map` starts to deviate from what you expect to what you are not expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting the same `List<Investor>` against all keys, because you are reusing the same list over and over. Instead:

- create a new list when you find you have a new key
- retrieve the existing list when you have an existing key

Like this:

```
List<Investor> list;
for(Investor investor : registerdUsers) {
     formatedDate = sdf.format(investor.getRegistrationDate());
     if (dateWiseInvestorsMap.containsKey(formatedDate)) {
         list = dateWiseInvestorsMap.get(formattedDate);
     } else {
         list = new ArrayList<Investor>();
         dateWiseInvestorsMap.put(formatedDate, list);
     }
     list.add(investor);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! my Question now Is why not dateWiseInvestorsList.clear() is working??

Comment: `clear()` is "working", because you assigned a list to `dateWiseInvestorsList` earlier in the code (ie it's not null), but you should not use `clear()` and you should not reuse the list over and over.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably reusing the `dateWiseInvestorsList` and inserting *the same object* all over. Try the following:

```
 for(Investor investor : registerdUsers) {
    formatedDate = sdf.format(investor.getRegistrationDate());
    dateWiseInvestorsList = (List) dateWiseInvestorsMap.get(formatedDate);
    if( dateWiseInvestorsList != null ) {
        dateWiseInvestorsList.add(investor);
    } else {
        dateWiseInvestorsList = new ArrayList<Investor>();
        dateWiseInvestorsList.add(investor);
        dateWiseInvestorsMap.put(formatedDate, dateWiseInvestorsList);
    }
}
```